# how to properly make a count function work for all the dynamically generated buttons?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I was writing a code to add 1 every time a button is pressed also the button is dynamically generated so are the table rows. the problem is i cant make the function work properly if there are second or third any other rows. I know the problem is that every button has the same class hence the count will always picks up where the other button left off.

```
$("form").submit(function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();  
    var name = $("input[name='name']").val(); 
     
   
    $(".data-table tbody").append("<tr data-name='"+name+"' class='vote'><td>"+name+"</td><td><button class='but' id="+name+">VOTE</button></td><td><button class='btn btn-info btn-xs btn-edit'>Edit</button><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs btn-delete'>Delete</button></td><td></td></tr>");  
    $("input[name='name']").val(''); 
    });
// the code to count
let count = 1;
$("tbody").on("click", ".but", function(){

        $(this).parents("tr").find("td:eq(3)").html('<span>'+count+'</span>');
        return count++;
        
    });
```

to be clear......
#1
Name     button      count
john          4
jane          0

#2 after one press of button on jane
Name     button      count
john          4
jane          5
i want to be able to count the number on Jane from 1 when pressed on her corresponding button

also i'm trying not to use any plugins

and Thank you for helping.

Comment: Can we [see your HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), too?

Comment: Java != Javascript

Answer (score 0):

First **replace**

```
       `<button class='but' id="+name+">VOTE</button> `
```

**with**

```
       <button class='but' id="+name+" data-count="clicked-0">VOTE</button>
```

now your **count code**

```
$("tbody").on("click", ".but", function() {
    let obj = $(this);
    let clicks = obj.attr('data-count').replace('clicked-','');
    clicks++;
    obj.attr('data-count','clicked-'+clicks);
    obj.parents("tr").find("td:eq(3)").html('<span>' + clicks + '</span>');
});
```